# npm doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm

I just downloaded NodeJS and npm, but when I try installing packages, it doesn't work.

This is the output in the terminal:

```
/home/alex
├── pug@2.0.0-rc.4 
├── pug-cli@1.0.0-alpha6 
└── stylus@0.54.5 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/alex/package.json'
npm WARN alex No description
npm WARN alex No repository field.
npm WARN alex No README data
npm WARN alex No license field.
```

It is probably an easy solution, but since I am new to this I'm thankful for answers!

Comment: You just downloaded, didn't you install it? Tell us how that once done!

Comment: Try this `npm install npm@latest -g` and let see

Comment: @George what I meant was install, sorry for my bad word choice! When I ran your code and tried installing a package from npm I instead got the output `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ok I see  are you creating a project if so you  need to run `npm install -g initialize` , then do `npm init` in the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `npm init` command in the directory where your creating your project.

[Except from npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init):

> This will ask you a bunch of questions, and then write a package.json for you.
>
> It attempts to make reasonable guesses about what you want things to be set to, and then writes a package.json file with the options you've selected.
>
> If you already have a package.json file, it'll read that first, and default to the options in there.
>
> It is strictly additive, so it does not delete options from your package.json without a really good reason to do so.
>
> If you invoke it with -f, --force, -y, or --yes, it will use only defaults and not prompt you for any options.

So when you run:

```
npm init
```

That `.json` file will be setup for your project.